# Kafka Connect Source Connector - Out of memory issue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have written a custom Kafka Connect plugin to read a file and publish avro messages to a topic. I am using `LineNumberReader` to read each line in the file and marry the record to the schema and publish to the topic. The records get published only when I return a list of `SourceRecord` in poll method. Sometimes, if its a large file, I run into Out of Memory issue. I've looked into this issue and read many blogs and questions on SO but nothing seems to work for me. I read about `commit()` method in `SourceTask` class but not very clear about it. Has someone come across similar issue? Code snippet below:

```
 @Override
public List<SourceRecord> poll() throws InterruptedException {
final List<SourceRecord> results = new ArrayList<>();
//Get reader based on certain params:
FileReader reader = myReader;
while (reader.hasNext()) {
    results.add(getSourceRecord(file, reader.currentOffset(), reader.next()));
   }
 return results;
}

private getSourceRecord convert(String fileName, Offset offset, Struct struct) {
    return new SourceRecord(
            new HashMap<String, Object>() {
                {
                    put("path", fileName);
                }
            },
            Collections.singletonMap("offset", offset.getRecordOffset()),
            config.getWriteTopic(),
            struct.schema(),
            struct
    );
}

public boolean hasNext() {
    if (currentLine != null) {
        return true;
    } else if (finished) {
        return false;
    } else {
        try {
            while (true) {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                offset.setOffset(reader.getLineNumber());
                if (line == null) {
                    finished = true;
                    return false;
                }
                currentLine = line;
           //Removed for brevity     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: @SahilChhabra - Shared the code.

Comment: Why don't you just increase the heap size of your connect worker?

Comment: @cricket_007 - I am already doing that but wondering if doing that is the only solution. From the startup logs, jvm.args = -Xmx3072M, -XX:+UseG1GC.. This is the only setting I've changed so far, everything else is default.

Comment: How about adding a configuration parameter for a maximum amount of lines instead of sending an entire filereader though a ConnectRecord?

Comment: By the way, there are already connectors that read files from directories. How is yours different from the included FileStreamSource or this one?https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/jcustenborder/kafka/connect/spooldir/SpoolDirSourceConnector.java

Comment: @cricket_007 I have to read the files from a topic, one at a time and then do further logic to deduce schema and and then publish messages to different topics. So, I can't use the default one. I haven't taken a look at the one that you provided link for, would do that. I am trying the batch size logic that I came across in FileStreamSourceConnector and will see if it works.

Comment: I see... If you're already reading from a topic, any reason you're not using Kafka Streams to do that? There aren't very many examples of Kafka Connect reading and writing between two topics

Comment: That's true. Let's just say that I've to live with this for now. :)